# Flag reason for closing as offtopic because of modded Minecraft tech support

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, flags, minecraft

Crashes etc. of modded Minecraft are off-topic here. But what is the appropriate flag?

- The content is not unreleased or illegal.
- It's not about game design/development.
- It's not asking to identify or recommend a game.
- It has to do with gaming.
- It doesn't belong on a different SE site.

Comment: If you can't yet Vote to Close:  Flag -> Should be closed -> Off Topic -> Custom Reason for "Modded Minecraft Tech Support"

Comment: @Robotnik I'm pretty sure that doesn't appear for those who can't actually close.  Best they can do is a blantantly off-topic flag.

Comment: @Frank - ah, fair enough. I hardly ever visit the flag option these days. 'Blatantly off topic' would also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think most people vote to close the question as either **unclear what you're asking** or **too broad**. Both of these reasons fit well enough, since without a list of mods the question is obviously unclear (since we don't have enough info to accurately assess the situation to begin with), or if they do have a list, it's still too broad because any of those mods could be causing the issue.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out [the list of error codes for Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) question we have.  Although its for vanilla Minecraft, we get a lot of crash questions for the vanilla game as well that include an error code of some sort.  A lot of the time, we can close them as a duplicate of the error code question.

Comment: A question was asked today about Forge: Whenever the person wants to start the installer, it opens as archive instead. That is a technical issue with modded Minecraft, but it isn't broad or unclear, so I didn't flag it. Was that correct? Technically it would have been better on SuperUser ("how to execute .jar"), but not really accepted for migration, because it's low quality.